# python doctest truncates expected output

Tags: python, doctest

I want to run this doctest and check the output:

```
>>> execfile("scss_converter_1.5.1_v1.py") #doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE +DONT_ACCEPT_BLANKLINE
body {

    .boxholder {

        .box {

            .col {

                .something {

                    .something.else {

                    }

                }

                img {

                }

                a {

                    .my.span {

                    }

                }

                ul {

                    .list-item {

                    }

                }

                #some-button {

                }

            }

        }

        .another-box.crazy.very.insane {

        }

    }

}
"""
```

But when I run the test it says the expected output is:

```
Expected:
    body {
```

Any way to make it expect the full string with all the words? A new line usually means the end of the expected output doesn't it so it is tricky.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized), the expected output of a doctest ends at an all-whitespace line or a line starting with `>>>`. If the whitespace lines are an essential part of the output, you can escape them by replacing all the blank lines with `<BLANKLINE>`.